# Is this correct grammar?

Tags: grammar

One of the casters in a game said this about the betting odds of one of the teams playing at the time-

1. "These ***are*** the best odds I ***have seen*** them have"

Shouldn't it be "These ***have been*** the best odds..."?

Similarly,

2a) I ***am*** the best thing you will have.

or

2b) I ***will be*** the best thing you will have.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Both sentences are comparing the situation **now** with (1) all the odds there have been in the past, and (2) the possible future. That is why the present tense is used.

Comment: So, in 2a, implication is that the person will not be the best thing in the future but only in the present moment?

Comment: In 2a, the implication is that, at some in the future, you will realise that I have been (at that time) the best thing that you have ever had.

Comment: So don't you think it would be better if I said " I will have been the best thing you will have"?

Comment: What is a "caster"?  The dictionary defines it as "An undriven wheel that is designed to be attached to the bottom of a larger object."  but that doesn't fit this context.

Comment: @JamesK I think OP means "sportscaster".

Comment: No, it would not be better. The sense is "I (who you have now) am better than anyone else you have now or will have in the future".

Comment: @KateBunting Ok, just one last question, can I say (1) as "these have been existing as the best odds for them", in this way the best odds were present in the past as well as in the present at the time of speaking. I simply used the Present Perfect Continuous tense.

Comment: Doesn't sound at all natural. What's wrong with "These are the best odds they have ever had"?

Comment: Aight, thanks! Catch you on the flip side!